# Are there any modern tradeoffs that come with designing more efficient DC-DC switching power converters?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, efficiency

Are there common metrics that usually degrade (ex. ramp time, line/load regulation, low-load efficiency) when pursuing more efficient designs, especially for isolated converters?

If you saw a new isolated high-power DC-DC converter advertising 99% efficiency, what performance factors would you be skeptical about?

(sorry if this is too broad again, still getting used to what scope I should write my questions at, and I have a lot of questions I'd like to ask.)

Comment: Cost. Cost is an important engineering design metric.

Comment: for EMI control, you need multi-layer PCBs; if  the SwitchReg radiates, then 99% is doubtful;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The high edge rates that high efficiency high frequency DC-DC converters usually require can potentially generate harmonic EMI/RFI across a vast range of EM spectrum (multiple HF shortwave bands and up), even if within legal (U.S. FCC, Part 15) RF limits.  Good EMI/RFI filtering on the output and shielding of both the converter and the input feed cabling, both in design, and across component tolerances over a large production run can add to product cost.  Mechanical stress, aging, and connection oxidation can allow an increase in any emitted EMI over time.

Comment: The RF hash generated, by multiple solar panel, computer, USB, and LED lighting (etc.) switching voltage converters, can pretty much destroy shortwave (and amateur) radio reception over entire neighborhoods.